# Angular Service not Saving Data

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use a service to share data between two controllers, but the data is not saved in the service. 
My Serice

```
angular.module('dataservice', []).
    factory('DataService', function(){
        var item = {};

        var addItem = function(newObj) {
            item = newObj;
        };

        var getItem  = function(){
            return item;
        };

        return {
            addItem: addItem,
            getItem: getItem
        };

});
```

My Controller

```
angular.module('App.controllers', []).    
    controller('SaveController', function($scope, $routeParams, APIService,DataService){
        $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
        $scope.book = null;      
        APIService.getBook($scope.id).success(function(response){
            $scope.book = response;
            DataService.add($scope.book);//add to service

        });        

    }).
    controller('ReadController', function($scope,DataService){
        $scope.book = null;
        $scope.book = DataService.get();//get from service

    })
```

Using chrome dev tools to inspect when i try to read the data, i just get the object definition i.e DataService = Object {}.

Thanks

Comment: azdonal, check my answer..

Comment: @developer033 thanks, i had a system crash immediately after putting up the question, just restored it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have a `factory` in another `module`, so you must **inject** it to your **main** *module* like this:

```
angular.module('App.controllers', ['dataservice'])
```

Then, you can call that `DataService` `factory`..

**Note:** You're trying to access the methods `add` and `get`, but actually they're named respectively as `addItem` and `getItem`, so you should rename them.